# Symfony 2 Form Theming Each Row?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have been over the docs many times, but I can not seem to find a simple answer to my question. In my form, how do I apply a themed block to each row of my form, so that the right classes can be applied.

To explain, I currently have this in my twig template:

```
{% form_theme form 'XXBundle:Themes/floatRows.html.twig' %}

  {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'MyIDForm'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.row1) }}
        {{ form_row(form.row2) }}
        {{ form_row(form.row2) }}
  {{ form_end(form) }}
```

In my theme file:

```
{% block form_row %}
  <div class="ftLeft">
    {%- if form.parent is empty -%}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {%- endif -%}

    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

However what I am trying to do is this,

In my theme file I want,

```
{% block FloatLeft %}
  <div class="ftLeft">
    {%- if form.parent is empty -%}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {%- endif -%}

    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block FloatRight %}
  <div class="ftRight">
    {%- if form.parent is empty -%}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {%- endif -%}

    {{- form_label(form) -}}
    {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    {{- form_errors(form) -}}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Then to be able to apply each of these blocks to each row in turn (or wherever else I want them):

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'MyIDForm'}}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.row1) }} <-Block FloatLeft
        {{ form_row(form.row2) }} <-Block FloatRight
        {{ form_row(form.row2) }} <-No Block, no float class!
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

All help all ways welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem. I just solved it by extending twig with new simple functions. If you don't know how to go to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643426/unknow-function-error-when-calling-twig-extension)
Your function and your template must have the same name.

Comment: many thanks, I take a look at it when I can. For now what I did was to just remove the div wrapper and then warp each form element in its own div with its own set of classes. Maybe not the best way but if I have to build a custom Twig function for it, then I have to do that later.  Many thanks.